# Excel dynamic attributes weights

Tags: excel

I have a tables of companies with attributes and attributes weights like this:

|  | attr_1 | attr_2 | attr_3 | attr_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| attr_weight | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 |

|  | attr_1 | attr_2 | attr_3 | attr_4 | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| company_1 | + | + | + |  | 4 |
| company_2 | + |  | + | + | 5 |
| company_3 | + | + | + | + | 7 |

So how can I connect attributes with their weights to be able to change attribute weights dynamically if necessary. For example, if I change attr_1 to 2, then the Result field will increase by 1 for all companies
I can't even generate the right search query, I need at least the name of the desired function

Comment: Try this formula: `=SUMIF(B4:E4,"+",B$2:E$2)`

Comment: Consider using 1 and 0 instead of + and blanks in your second table. Then your calculation will be a simple linear equation: =sumproduct(attr_weight,company_id). Otherwise, second solution by @harun24hr below is foolproof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try the following formula-

```
=SUM(XLOOKUP(FILTER($B$5:$E$5,B6:E6="+"),$B$1:$E$1,$B$2:$E$2))
```

For older versions could try-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$E$2)*(B6:E6="+"))
```

[image]